# Issue about the return value of activityStarting

Tags: android

Today I'm developing an App which can intercept the launch between activities, My key code is:

```
ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().setActivityController(new InterceptActivityController(), false);

private class InterceptActivityController extends IWeChatActivityController.Stub {

    void InterceptActivityController() {}

    @Override
    public boolean activityStarting(Intent intent, String pkg) { 
        showDialog();
        return false;
    }
}

private void showBottomDialog() {
    Log.d(TAG, "showBottomDialog");
    Dialog bottomDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
    bottomDialog.setContentView(contentView);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = contentView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    contentView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);        
    bottomDialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    bottomDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);        
    bottomDialog.show();
}
```

I defined a Button and planned to start an Activity after clicking it. But now I intercept this action and just show a dialog in the function of activityStarting and then return false, after dismissing this dialog, I click the button again, but nothing works, dialog doesn't show any more, Who knows the reason ? Maybe I think this is a google source bug, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You know the Dialogs need to be Shown in a Timely manner. I mean You need the Dialog to be Shown for How Long? When you Start showing a Dialog and Dismiss it, It's Not Destroyed, It's just Dismissed.

Look at the Code below. I wrote this in my own app, It's Safe. Try it and see if you're satisfied with it:

```js
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {



        bottomDialog.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {


              for (int i = 0; i <= 1200; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(100); //The time it takes to update i
                if (i = 1200) {
                  bottomDialog.dismiss();
                }
              }


            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }).start();

      }
```

You can use AsyncTask as well. Also, I put the whole thing in a Click Listener just to show how it can be used.

The idea is define a showing Time for the Dialog

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found out I made a mistake, actually I'm intercepting a page in WeChat with a Button which is not actually a real Button, it's a WebView, now I've solved it by using other methods, Thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you figured it out